# Flow to create multiple Account objects, but also allow look up of existing record

Tags: visual-workflow

Any help or guidance much appreciated. I am new to Salesforce development, and have been researching solutions but wasn't able to find something that applied to my use case as whole.

Scenario:
We use Salesforce hiearchy to facilitate report provisioning (via our custom API)  and services to Accounts, and visibility of data is based on their Salesforce hiearchy.

- Currently users are creating each account separately during the sales process
- Inaccurate Account data creates error in the visibility of information
- We want to create efficiencies and guide users
- We have 3 Account Records involved in this. Maker, Distributor and Office.
- Makers may be the Parent of one or many Distributors
- All Distributors must have a Maker as a Parent
- A Distributor may be the parent of one or many Offices
- An Office can only have a Distributor as a Parent
- We have opportunity types for Makers & Distributors.

My thought was to build this as a guided screenflow to create the 3 accounts in the correct tiers and also include lookup fields to include for any existing Makers or Distributor accounts

I initially tried building this as a screen flow but could not resolve the 3 tier hiearchy or the lookup of any existing entities (Makers & Distributors) based on my experience and research.

Any helpful comments would be appreciated. I have included an example diagram with the fields to be set on each Account object.

[image: example of Account hiearchy]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.